# Java apk launch using intent

Tags: java, android

Good day! I'm new to Android. I am writing a program with only two buttons that call the system application from the system's depths. There are a lot of bugs everywhere. Please help me! I still can't figure it out.

**Main Activity**

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openApkButtonClick(View view) {
        String packageName = "com.yfvet.engineeringmode";
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "APK not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Button openButton = findViewById(R.id.openButton2);
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openApkFile();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openApkFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file:///system/app/EngineeringMode.apk"); // Replace with your APK file path
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SVIEngineeringMode"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

**gradle**

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 34

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.7.0'
    implementation 'android.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'

}
```

I wrote something in the gradle, made permissions in the Manifest, and tried a bunch of different codes for
MainActivity. A bunch of videos and forums have been read. But mistakes follow mistakes

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming *questions*. What is your question? If your question is "why does this not work?", then please explain what is not working. Note that `ACTION_VIEW` is not used on modern versions of Android for app installation (see `PackageInstaller`), and your app may not have read access to that filesystem location.